# Regarding pulling references from another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Im trying to build a library that I can reuse between projects, but sadly not all references from said library gets "pulled" to the application project referencing the library... hope im clear..

Let me explain. I have reproduced the problem at a smaller scale, here is the setup. I have a visual studio solution containing 2 projects:

- SomeLib (.net framework class library)
- TestApp (wpf application)

TestApp references SomeLib.
I added 2 nugets (and dependencies) to SomeLib:

- SharpDX.Direct2D
- Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit

SomeLib contains this class:

```
    public class TestMe
    {
        public TestMe()
        {
            SharpDX.Direct2D1.AntialiasMode thing = SharpDX.Direct2D1.AntialiasMode.Aliased;//use sharpdx for ... something.
        }
    }
```

...and this WPF Usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeLib.TestView"
    ...
    xmlns:xtk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:xad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock">
    <Grid>
        <xad:DockingManager>
            <xad:DockingManager.Theme>
                <xad:VS2010Theme />
            </xad:DockingManager.Theme>
            <xad:LayoutRoot>
            </xad:LayoutRoot>
        </xad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TestApp has a MainWindow using this xaml:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:SomeLib="clr-namespace:SomeLib;assembly=SomeLib" x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <SomeLib:TestView/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and this code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }
        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SomeLib.TestMe thing = new SomeLib.TestMe();
        }
    }
```

Now after build I check the output folder and notice the SharpDX assemblies got "pulled" there, but not the Xceed ones.

Interestingly, using the visual studio designers on the view and window I can see AvalonDock getting instanciated there, with no errors.

When running, I get this error: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock

...well of course.

Now what am I missing? why are the SharpDX assemblies properly "pulled" to the child project but not the Xceed ones?

**EDIT**:
Thanks Zinov; using any of the objects contained inside the Xceed reference *from c# code* does work and makes it so the child project has the dll in its output fodler. So at this point question is, is there a way of doing that from XAML?

Comment: Did you try to instantiate in your main project a dummy object from Xceed and compile again to see if it pulls the other assembly?

Comment: Without adding the Xceed nuget to the main project it doesn't work. Adding the nuget works. In fact, if I add the Xceed nuget to the main project, the code as described in my question works also. (dlls are in the bin folder..)

Comment: ...But im trying to get all the nugets in a central location mainly for management.

Comment: how you are loading the assemblies?

Comment: Just adding them as references to the projects. wpf/.net handles the rest. The main problem here is that not all the dlls are copied in the build output folder.

Comment: which version of .net are you using? .Net Framework or .Net Core?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2 for both class library and wpf app, in VS2019, which I like a lot.

Comment: It should include the references after you compile if you have the nugets included in your project

Comment: The references are added to the class library project by the nugget system just fine. The main point here is, after referencing that class library from a wpf app, some of the references gets copied to the output folder (SharpDX) but not others (Xceed). I would believe that it should work (or not) for both..

Comment: If I also add the nugets to the main wpf app everything works just fine, but im trying to avoid adding the nugets to all my projects..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191881/discussion-between-zinov-and-remi-beaulieu).

Comment: At this point I understand that the dlls are not copied simply because nothing from the child project (wpf app) actually and actively references them. (not even the xaml, which point to some online schema) If you post that answer Zinov you will get the cred.